# Django : How to return an object from a python module

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django and I got exposed to OOP in python very recently. I am not able to understand the below piece of code which is explained under the 'views' in Django Book.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
          return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

In the above code snippet ,it is explained that the function hello takes 'request' as a mandatory input arg ,which is actually an object . 
"The function is a simple one-liner: it merely returns an HttpResponse object that has been instantiated with the text "Hello world"."

I am here trying to understand the above snippet.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That explanation is correct. What, exactly, did you not understand? And this appears to be normal procedural programming, nothing particularly OOP-related here.

Comment: Why dont you see the code in its entirety. The web page triggers the URL that actually calls this view named `hello`, and the response being sent to the template. It will help you put things into perspective a lot better

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly what is written in the Django Book.

`hello` is a function, that resides inside the `views.py` and is considered a view function.

In Django, view function expect to get a `request` argument which represents a `HttpRequest` object that has information about the request sent from the client to the server. One of them would be the GET parameters (for instance).

This view  only does a simple thing, it returns an object of the type `HttpResponse` that is returned to the client. This object was instantiated with the string "Hello World" that will be presented to the client.

All view functions need to return a `HttpResponse` object of some sort - including but not limited to `HttpResponseRedirect`, `Http404` etc..
If they don't the Django framework acts accordingly (can throw an exception, for instance, but not necessarily)